# Не работает JS на странице

Tags: javascript

Запускаю через liveserver html-файл - и вижу только разметку без js.

В html:  
Модуль JS main.js лежит в папке.

Модуль импортирует другие файлы, которые должны делать генерацию фото по шаблону html. И ничего нет совсем:

```js
//main.js

import { somePhotos } from './data.js';
import { renderThumbnails } from './thumbnail.js';

renderThumbnails(somePhotos);
```

```html
 <script type="module" src="js/main.js"></script>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что в консоли пишет?